# Test clojure instance in deftest

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

I want to check if the right instance is used.
But while the repl gives me true, the actual test returns nil.
Idk why

---

```
(ns my-app.queue)

(def queue (atom clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY))
```

---

```
(ns my-app.queue-test
  (:require [my-app.queue :as sut]
            [clojure.test :refer :all]))

(deftest queue-type-test
  (is (instance? clojure.lang.PersistentQueue @sut/queue)))

;repl output
;(instance? clojure.lang.PersistentQueue @sut/queue) ;=> true
```

The command `lein test` gives me:
`FAIL in (queue-type-test) (queue_test.clj:6)
expected: (instance? clojure.lang.PersistentQueue (clojure.core/deref sut/queue))
  actual: nil`

I know the test itself is not really useful, but I can't figure out why this behaves like this.

Comment: Small detail, but the first namespace declaration and import in your code don't align.

Comment: Could it be that another test resets the atom to nil?

Comment: I have the same result running  
`lein test :only my-app.queue-test`

Comment: It works great for me. Try running `lein clean`, verify your namespaces are all OK, and re-run `lein test`.

Comment: Maybe you could reproduce this in a git project.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: both `is` and `@` are macros. Most obvious fix would be something like:

```
(deftest queue-type-test
  (let [queue @sut/queue]
    (is (instance? clojure.lang.PersistentQueue queue)))
```

`clojure.test` docs don't make it immediately obvious, but `is` is a pretty tricky macro that looks inside its body. Here's a snippet from the docstring:

```
user> (is (= 5 (+ 2 2)))

FAIL in  (:1)
expected: (= 5 (+ 2 2))
  actual: (not (= 5 4))
false
```

Notice `actual: (not (= 5 4))`. It's clear that it did not evaluate `=` so that it can show us the result of `(+ 2 2)`. [Here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/2e0c0a9a89ede8221504edeb90e8c4ee6cce7e16/src/clj/clojure/test.clj#L475) are all the special cases for `assert-expr` multimethod.